If there is no statute of limitations, can I be forced to bring a suit?
If there is no statute of limitations on a forged documents case, can I be forced to file suit before I am ready to do so?

Can you clarify what jurisdiction you are in? The global answer is very broad.

By "forced", do you mean that you must file whether you want to or not, as in bdb484's answer, or that if you do not file, that will be held against you in your case?

@Cadence based on "before I am ready" I think they're asking if the absence of a SoL gives them indefinite time to investigate before filing the suit.

A statute of limitations or other limitation like laches doesn't ever force you to bring a suit, but it can make it impossible to do so, or affect the outcome, if you wait too long.
A statue of limitations is a deadline after which you are unable to bring legal action. Even within the statute of limitations, however, a lawsuit can be dismissed is it's determined that the plaintiff waited an "unreasonable" amount of time to file the suit - this is the concept of laches. Basically, a plaintiff can't suffer immediate and significant damages, and then wait a long time to do anything about it (possibly as the damages compound further), as it may impede the defense's ability to retain or show relevant evidence, and by choosing the timing of the filing, the plaintiff can possibly prejudice the available evidence in their favor.

I'm not sure this is really correct. Laches is generally limited to requests for equitable relief. In claims for monetary/legal relief, the interests you're talking about are protected instead by a statute of limitations, mitigation requirements, etc.

Also limitation deadlines aren't always impossible to overcome. Consider for example Section 118(1)(b) of the Equality Act 2010 which allows the court to bypass the usual 6 month limitation period if it is "just and equitable" to do so. It may also be possible for the parties to agree to a different deadline with a standstill agreement.

@bdb484 Laches can still be relevant within the statute of limitations. I don't really see much detail in the question about exactly what type of legal action is being considered. Here's one case where laches didn't bar the suit entirely, but did factor into the monetary damages: https://casetext.com/analysis/supreme-court-rules-laches-no-bar-to-monetary-damages-for-copyright-infringement-claim

Another factor is that the perpetrator may die, triggering a non-claim deadline in the probate process, or may file a bankruptcy, triggering a deadline to file an adversary action in the bankruptcy case to prevent it from being discharged in bankruptcy.

@bdb484 Many states, including Colorado (as of 2014), permit laches as a defense to claims that do not arise in equity. https://law.justia.com/cases/colorado/supreme-court/2014/12sc198.html

@bdb484, it may not be latches specifically, but nearly every legal system has some variation on a rule that requires you to file suit or take other actions within a reasonable time after you discover you've been harmed.

@Mark Yes, in the United States and other common law systems, it's called a "statute of limitations."

No. A statute of limitations says that you may not file after a certain time.
The absence of a statute of limitations does not mean that you must file at any time. You are basically always free to not file at all.

Absence of a specific SoL can mean a general SoL kicks in.

What about laches?

Laches also cannot force you to file a suit. It can put a limit on when you can bring an equitable claim, but it generally doesn't apply to legal claims.

@bdb484 Although we're waiting for the OP to clarify, I think its reasonable to assume that they didn't mean forced as in you must file even if you don't want to but rather that you must file if you want to ultimately succeed in the claim.

I agree with @JBentley. The operative phrase is "before I'm ready" -- they want to know if they can wait until they do a full investigation.
